# AngularJS repeat dynamic array values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have this array:

```
[
    {type:'a', value:'234'}, 
    {type:'a', value:'5566'}, 
    {type:'b', value:'778'}, 
    {type:'c', value:'899'}, 
    {type:'k', value:'5644'}
]
```

I want to do this iteration:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array">
    <h3 ng-bind="obj.type"></h3>
    <span ng-bind="obj.value"></span>
</div>
```

I want the result to be header for each type without duplicates, and under each type I want the values. 
How can I do it without iterating and creating new arrays?

Desired result:

```
<div>
    <h3>a</h3>
    <span>234</span>
    <span>234</span>
</div>...
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure it is `obj.name` and not `obj.value`??

Comment: And can you post the expected output that you need like in code?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, your iteration doesn't match your described result.  The iteration you are demonstrating will only ever show the **first** `value` to match a given `type`.  It sounds more like you are wanting to group these together, which would require a second `ng-repeat`.  Can you clarify which you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi. Updated my desired result.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want `234` and `5566`, not `234` twice;  still, it will take 2 `<span>` elements instead of one and another `ng-repeat` to accomplish something close to what you are expecting.  also, it requires changing your data structure somewhat.  My recommended solution is to use underscore.js to help us here;  I'll work up a sample and post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve the result you are looking for is to use underscore.js `_.groupBy` http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy.  This will require changing the iterators slightly as well.

Using `$scope.groups = _.groupBy($scope.array, "type");`, we get:

```js
{
  "a": [{
    "type": "a",
    "value": "234"
  }, {
    "type": "a",
    "value": "5566"
  }],
  "b": [{
    "type": "b",
    "value": "778"
  }],
  "c": [{
    "type": "c",
    "value": "899"
  }],
  "k": [{
    "type": "k",
    "value": "5644"
  }]
}
```

Using `ng-repeat`, we would not get the exact result expected.  However, we can use the `(key, value)` variation of `ng-repeat` to achieve the result we are looking for, something like this:

```html
<div ng-repeat="(type, values) in groups">
  <h3 ng-bind="type"></h3>
  <span ng-repeat="v in values">
        <span ng-bind="v.value"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Full Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('stackExample', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{
    type: 'a',
    value: '234'
  }, {
    type: 'a',
    value: '5566'
  }, {
    type: 'b',
    value: '778'
  }, {
    type: 'c',
    value: '899'
  }, {
    type: 'k',
    value: '5644'
  }];

  $scope.groups = _.groupBy($scope.array, "type");
  console.log($scope.groups);
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
<script data-require="underscore.js@1.8.3" data-semver="1.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="stackExample">

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(type, values) in groups">
    <h3 ng-bind="type"></h3>
    <span ng-repeat="v in values">
        <span ng-bind="v.value"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But the OP has ask that he does not want to create another array. The answer is good but I think it can be optimized a little more.....

Comment: @dvenkatsagar quite frankly, there isn't a reasonable way to accomplish the output expected with the data in the original structure, without some intermediary data refactor.  even your answer of using unique doesn't perfectly work, since it is only outputting one row for each type.

Comment: I agree, thats why Im trying to figure out how to achieve it without using any additional libraries. :)

Comment: He doesn't have to create an array that continues to exist. It can exist just for the one function. That is, instead of `groups` being a variable it can be a function: 
    `$scope.groups = function (array) {return _.groupBy($scope.array, "type");};`

The HTML would then be: `<div ng-repeat="(type, values) in groups(array)">`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array | unique : 'type'">
  <h3 ng-bind="obj.type"></h3>
  <span ng-bind="obj.value"></span>
</div>
```

Check it out and see if it works.

Edit : You would need the [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module for this

Update:

Looking at the updated question, I think it might be difficult for you to achieve the operation given(using a single iteration to list out all the values by unique type).

But you can do one thing, group the array by type using this pure JS function(similar to @Claies answer):

```
var custom_sort = function(arr){
  var a = arr.slice(0);
  var ret = [];
  var same_type = false;
  while (a.length != 0){
    var item = a.shift();
    if(ret.length > 0){
      for(var i = 0; i < ret.length; i++){
        if(ret[i].type == item.type){
          ret[i].value.push(item.value);
          same_type = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if(!same_type){
      ret.push({type : item.type, value : [item.value]});
    }
    same_type = false;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The output array that you will get is like this:

```
[ 
  { type: 'a', value: [ '234', '5566' ] },
  { type: 'b', value: [ '778' ] },
  { type: 'c', value: [ '899' ] },
  { type: 'k', value: [ '5644' ] } 
]
```

And from there, do the iteration like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array">
  <h3 ng-bind="obj.type"></h3>
  <div ng-repeat="v in obj.value">
    <span ng-bind="v"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The function is essentially what the underscorejs `_.groupby` function mentioned in the first answer does.

Comment: I'm just giving an approach that doesn't need the import of an entire library, just for one function

Answer (score 0):

You need [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

You can do like this

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in array | unique:'type' ">
    <h3 ng-bind="obj.type"></h3>
    <span ng-bind="obj.name"></span>
</div>
```

Define your app module like this.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);
```

I have used `angular-filter.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do some coding for it in your controller to provide a filtered dataSet to ngRepeat.

```
        var dataSet = [
            {type:'a', value:'234'}, 
            {type:'a', value:'5566'}, 
            {type:'b', value:'778'}, 
            {type:'c', value:'899'}, 
            {type:'k', value:'5644'}
        ];

        var filteredDataSet = new Array();
        dataSet.forEach(function(dataObj){
            var tempObject = {};
            tempObject.type  = dataObj.type;
            tempObject.value = new Array(dataObj.value);

            var duplicate_key = false;
            if (filteredDataSet.length){
                filteredDataSet.forEach(function(iObj){
                    // Push value into a value array of filteredDataSet 
                    // and make the flag duplicate_key value to true to 
                    // prevent the insertion of duplicate object into a 
                    // filteredDataSet array.
                    if (dataObj.type == iObj.type){
                        iObj.value.push(dataObj.value);
                        duplicate_key = true;
                    }
                });
            }
            // Push non duplicate object by key into a filteredDataSet array
            if (duplicate_key == false){
                filteredDataSet.push(tempObject);
            }
        });

        $scope.dataSet = filteredDataSet;
```

And here is your HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="dataObj in dataSet">
    <h1>{{dataObj.type}}</h1> 
    <div ng-repeat="val in dataObj.value">
        <h3>{{val}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it solve your problem, modification into this code will be highly appreciated thanks.